# What is the connection between the complex variety and real variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The complex variety and real variety are defined by the same set of polynomial $(f_1, f_2,...f_n)$ except the solution set one is defined over $\mathbb{C}$, the other is defined over $\mathbb{R}$. I know the dimension and degree of complex variety. The question is what are the dimension and degree of real variety. Any theorem, book, note relates this would be great.

This question arises when I solve a set of polynomial equations, I can use numerical algebraic geometry to get complex solution(complex variety) of this set of polynomial equations, but I really want is real solution of this set of polynomial equations(real variety). Right now, I have the dimension and degree of complex solution(complex variety), I just want to know the dimension and degree of the real variety?

Comment: What do you mean defined by the same ideal? The ideal $(x)$ of $\mathbb C[x]$ will not be the same ideal as the ideal $(x)$ of $\mathbb R[x]$.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "variety". What version of variety are you using?

Comment: Hi, I mean defined by the same set of polynomials, but the coefficient is in real field, complex variety means the solution in complex field, real variety means the solution in real field

Comment: If you mean a variety "in the classical sense", i.e. not a scheme, there is only a coarse relation between these concepts: the real dimension can be anything between 0 and the complex dimension (think about the zero locus of $\sum^m_{i=1} x_i^2$ as $m$ varies, for instance). You should really [edit] your question to include your full definitions - there are many different definitions of "variety" in use, and to give a good answer we need to know more about your setup.

Comment: Hi, KReiser. I edited it. Is this more clear?

Comment: It's a bit better now, please consider adding this sort of context from the start next time. (You may also be interested to know that you can ping other users commenting on your post by using an @ sign before their username - these notifications make conversations a bit easier.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only general relation between the dimension of the real points and the complex points of a variety is that the former is not more than the latter. Depending on your definition of "degree" (for instance, number of intersections counted appropriately with a generic complementary dimensional linear subspace), the notion may be worthless. This is one reason to upgrade to schemes - your theory behaves correctly over fields that aren't algebraically closed, and you can still answer questions like "does this have a real point" by descent theory and the like.

---

If you're looking for explicit real solutions of a system of polynomial equations, the best tools I'm aware of come from the area of semi-algebraic geometry. Specifically, what you'll want to do is compute a cylindrical algebraic decomposition of your set. This gives you a decomposition of the solution set as a finite union of sets which are semialgebraically isomorphic to $(0,1)^d$ and if two of these cells intersect after a coordinate projection, their images are equal. For an introduction, I like [these notes](https://gcomte.perso.math.cnrs.fr/M2/CosteIntroToSemialGeo.pdf) by Michel Coste; if you're looking to compute a specific example, [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html) has an implemenation as does [SAGE](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/qepcad.html), though I have never used either. (I've done work in semi-algebraic geometry, but my work almost never relies on computing a specific decomposition, so I'm not super familiar with the current bleeding edge of the implementation of the algorithm - just the existence is enough for my purposes most of the time).

Comment: I know a very little scheme theory from Gathmann's notes. According your answer, it seems semi-algebraic geometry is more likely suit my needs. Thanks.

Comment: @KReiser - How do we know that the dimension of the real part is bounded above by the dimension of the complex variety?

Comment: @OskarHenriksson Good question and I suppose what you mean by dimension matters for the details. Here's an outline of the argument I would make: pick a real point. If it's smooth, then it's smooth as a point of the complexification because this is measured by the rank of the Jacobian, which doesn't change under field extension. If singular, consider it as a point on the singular locus, a proper lower-dimensional subvariety and induct. If this doesn't quite resolve your issue, I'd encourage you to write a question so that we may discuss it there away from the character limits for comments.